# CSS Transitions are lagging in Chrome (Mac version 31) and Safari (version 6.1)

Tags: jquery, css, webkit, zurb-foundation

So I have built an off-canvas navigation using Foundation's off canvas example (http://zurb.com/playground/off-canvas-layouts) and it works beautifully in Firefox and Opera but not so beautifully in Chrome and Safari.

The CSS I am using is this:

```
[role="complementary"], [role="main"] { 
    width: 100%; 
    display: block; 
    position: relative; 
    -webkit-transition: 0.25s all ease-in; 
    -moz-transition: 0.25s all ease-in; 
    -o-transition: 0.25s all ease-in; 
    transition: 0.25s all ease-in; 
}
```

The issue I am having is that the background is not sliding in with the section, so that there is a noticeable flash of white before the background appears. Please note that the transition on webkit *is* happening, its just not happening with the background in place as it should.

I hope this is clear enough and that someone can help.

Note: I have tried putting in `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` to the CSS as I saw suggested somewhere but this made no difference.

Comment: Tough to tell without seeing the problem --  can you provide remake the thing in codepen or jsfiddle so we can check it out? That also may clarify where the problem is for you.

Comment: I just made it in jsBin and it seems to be working fine - so it must be some gumf that I have put in that shouldn't be there. Will try to refactor and that might help :-) thanks

Comment: A nice strategy to debug this kind of stuff is to delete elements of you web page using the web inspector and keep testing the animation as you remove stuff. When it runs smoothly, you can focus your efforts at the last thing you removed to figure out why it's problematic.